# C# Delegate from VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, delegates, handler

I have a legacy solution which has some C# projects (newest ones) and some VB projects (oldest ones). I know it is not a good practice, but it is what I have now, so I have to deal with it.

In a C# project I have some code like this:

```
public class MyObjectClass 
{
    ... more code here ...
    public delegate void SelectedItemChange(IMyInterface oldItem, IMyInterface newItem);
    public virtual SelectedItemChange SelectedItemChanged { get; set; }
}
```

And this works like a charm when I use it from another C# project this way:

```
public class MySecondaryClass
{
    ... more code here ...
    MyObjectClass MyObject = new();
    MyObject.SelectedItemChanged += (sender, args) => { DoSomething(); };
}
```

So far, so good. The problem is when I have to use the same delegate from a VB.NET project. I have tried this:

```
Public Class MySecondaryClassVB
   ... more code here ...
   Dim MyObject as MyObjectClass = New MyObjectClass()
   AddHandler MyObject.SelectedItemChanged, Sub(sender As Object, args As EventArgs)
                                                 DoSomething()
                                            End Sub
End Class
```

But `SelectedItemChanged` appears in Visual Studio underlined in red with the next error:

> 'SelectedItemChanged' is not an event of 'MyObjectClass'

I am not able to understand why it works in C# and not in VB.NET, so I guess my `AddHandler` syntax is not correct. What is the right syntax for this? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

UPDATE:
Maybe it is useful to understand the problem. The real MyObjectClass is there I emit the event:

```
public class MyObjectClass 
{
    ... more code here ...

    private IMyInterface _selectedItem;
    public IMyInterface SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set
        {
            IMyInterface oldSelectedItem = _selectedItem;
            _selectedItem = value;
            SelectedItemChanged?.Invoke(oldSelectedItem, _selectedItem);
            SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
        }
    }

    public delegate void SelectedItemChange(IMyInterface oldItem, IMyInterface newItem);
    public virtual SelectedItemChange SelectedItemChanged { get; set; }
}
```

Then I want to subscribe to that event from a C# project (and I do it with no problem), or from a VB.NET project (and I am not able to).

Comment: `AddHandler MyObject.SelectedItemChanged, Sub(s, a) DoSomething()` or just `AddHandler MyObject.SelectedItemChanged, Sub() DoSomething()` if you don't need to use the arguments. -- You can see the same thing in the C# code.

Comment: @Jimi yes, you are right, it was just an example. The real problem here is that it does not compile because of the error explained in the question. Thank you

Comment: What is `MyObject`? Is it the same object used in the C# code? Is that a custom event? What is the GUI Platform? -- The error implies that the object you're referencing doesn't expose a public event with that name. So, make sure you're dealing with the same Type.

Comment: @Jimi Yes, it is the same object. I have updated the question. I hope it is clearer now. Thank you

Comment: As the answer suggests, do you have a custom Event with that name also in the VB.Net part of code? `SelectedItemChanged` is not an *known* event. What is the GUI Platform? -- It cannot be the same object: in the VB.Net code you have `MySecondaryClassVB`

Comment: @Jimi I define in C# (MyObjectClass) this `public virtual SelectedItemChange SelectedItemChanged { get; set; }`. Then, also in C#, without defining anything more, it works when I use a MyClassObject object: `MyObject.SelectedItemChanged += (sender, args) => { DoSomething(); };`. Must I have a custom Event in VB when I do not need it in C#? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Jimi I have updated the question again, maybe I have not explained myself properly, or maybe I am missing something as you say. I will also review my code as you suggest. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that `SelectedItemChanged` will only ever refer to a single delegate then just create one and assign it, just as you would for any other property referring to any other object:

```vb
MyObject.SelectedItemChanged = New SelectedItemChange(Sub(sender, args) DoSomething())
```

If it might refer to multiple delegates then you can do explicitly what the C# `+=` operator is doing implicitly:

```vb
MyObject.SelectedItemChanged = [Delegate].Combine(MyObject.SelectedItemChanged, New SelectedItemChange(Sub(sender, args) DoSomething()))
```

It's worth noting here that your delegate is specific declared with two parameters of type `IMyInterface`. That means that, in this code:

```cs
MyObject.SelectedItemChanged += (sender, args) => { DoSomething(); };
```

both `sender` and `args` are inferred as that type. They are NOT `object` and `EventArgs`, as you have assumed for your VB code. That's an example of how the C# code is garbage.

Answer (score 1):

It´s because SelectedItemChange is not an event. You need to declare it as event

```
public event SelectedItemChange SelectedItemChange_Event;
```

Your AddHanler Syntax in VB is correct

Comment: But that part of the code is the one in the C# project that works properly. I want to change the code in the VB.NET part... how could I make this code work in VB? I do not know how to handle that delegate in VB, but I do not want to change the delegate. Thank you

Comment: The original post is an example of how C# is not immune to allowing bad code - the use of a property instead of an event is sloppy, but allowed in C#. In this case, VB demands an event declaration.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas this code was taken from "Mastering WPF 2nd edition", chapter 3, page 88. I cannot say if it is bad code or not.

Comment: @Carlos: There may be some special cases where it's required, but in general use 'event' when you want an event. I'm sure the author didn't agonize over every line of code in his book.

Comment: @zTim Two questions about your answer: 1) How do I handle the 2 parameters (oldItem and newItem) with your solution? 2) should then I invoke SelectedItemChange_Event and also SelectedItemChange? There is a lot of code now in C# that is subscribed to `SelectedItemChange`, so I need to invoke it. And I understand in your solution that I also have to invoke `SelectedItemChange_Event`. Is there a smarter approach to do it? Thank you

Comment: @Carlos you shouldn't have to rename anything.  If you explicitly call it an `event` on the C# side instead of a property, the rest should just work.  The only thing to watch out for is, the property is declared as `virtual` so there could be issues with polymorphic use (though that would be weird).  The "right" way to do this is to have a protected virtual `OnSelectedItemChanged` which the children can override.

Comment: @Craig yes, with your comment I have understood it. The only thing missing before accepting this answer is: how do I pass both parameters when I invoke the event? Thank you

Comment: @Carlos usually you just pass the args in the invocation.  On the VB side, you would `RaiseEvent SelectedItemChanged(arg1, arg2)`.  On the C# side, you would do `SelectedItemChanged?.Invoke(arg1, arg2);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Event SelectedItemChange_Event As SelectedItemChange
```